# Why is 3D so slow on iPad3 Through Cocoon JS?

Tags: javascript, ipad, 3d, three.js, cocoonjs

On a Nexus 7, the Gangnam Style Doom demo through CocoonJS runs at a healthy 35 FPS. On an iPad 3, the same demo runs at 5 FPS!

My own project (using ThreeJS)  runs at 50-60 FPS on a Nexus 7 and on a cheap $100 Android handset (Cubot P9), runs at 30FPS. On an iPad3, it runs at around 15 FPS.

Why so slow on the iPad? The iPad3 runs most 3D games just fine, nice and smooth.

My own tests seem to indicate this is related to the number of 3D objects,not the number of polygons e.g. 100 low-poly cubes (1200 polys) is slow, whereas one object with 6000 polygons runs fast.

I don't think this is a ThreeJS issue, as the Gangnam Doom demo uses PlayCanvas.

I'm surprised no one else has noticed this. Has anyone tested the Gangnam demo on iPad 4/Air?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the iPhone/iPad does not have 3d acceleration yet. That is why you get low FPS. On three.js you can choose which renderer to use. Either the WebGLRenderer (when there is acceleration) or the CanvasRenderer (when there is no acceleration). Android on the other hand, does support 3D acceleration so the speed you are seeing has only to do with how fast/slow the device is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think you are incorrect. You may be getting confused with in-browser WebGL acceleration not being available as standard on iPhone/iPad. Cocoon JS allows you to use 3D Acceleration by wrapping your JavaScript WebGL calls inside its Canvas+ wrapper. Look at the Cocoon JS environment-mapped heads demo - it is obviously accelerated.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was talking about browser based WebGL acceleration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware of up-coming WebGL support in-browser in iOS. However, my question relates to 3D running inside the Cocoon JS environment, not in the browser. It will interesting to see how the two compare.